# How make sure modem is already connected to phone line

Tags: c#, serial-port, at-command, modem

I just noticed that if modem was not connected to phone line and you open `SerialPort` and send an AT command like `"AT\r\n"` Then your app hangs for about +20 seconds. How can i make sure that already a phone line connected to modem?

Comment: Please don't say that client should Bend and look at behind of case for checking that! :D

Comment: Depends what you mean.  It's going to be impossible from the software point of view to tell the difference between - a) cable not plugged in, b) cable plugged in but cut half way, c) cable plugged in but not plugged in at other end, d) cable plugged in both ends but other end not plugged in.  So I don't think this physical check is possible.

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid the hang, you could run the modem calls in a background thread? (assuming this is a UI program and not a console app) I'd expect the [telephony API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would have function for this, although there's no (Microsoft-provided) .NET wrapper for it, only [a commercial wrapper](http://www.traysoft.com/addtapi_overview.htm?gclid=CKPL9omWsqcCFUEa4Qod4lli_A) comes up on Google (not tried, can't recommend it)

Comment: @mmye: WHAT!!! I just mean that if there is any signal in phone so modem is already connected other wise no! :D
.
@Rup: Thank you, but that's the exception-proof way of doing things. I mean waiting for exception or error on `SerialPort` to say "There is no phone line"? :-? not a good idea. I'm searching for a better way! Like windows when you try to connect using dialup and it alert you immediate! :-<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only open and close the `SerialPort` associated to device (modem for example). If it can't open it so it means it's not available.

Comment: As i say in previous comment it's exception-proof way! but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GetModemStatus to find the modem status.. if the modem is connected this function returns a specific value. i am not sure whether the value is same for every time.. in my pc this function returns 115.